# how to create a light font from a preferred font?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to get a "light" weight font from a UIFontTextStyle font style.
Whatever the code (on stackoverflow or in the doc), i always get a "normal" weight font.

For example:

```
    var descriptor = UIFontDescriptor.GetPreferredDescriptorForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyle.Caption2);
    att = descriptor.FontAttributes;
    att.Traits = new UIFontTraits {Weight = (float?)UIFontWeightConstants.Light};
    font = UIFont.FromDescriptor(descriptor, 0);
    //t = font.DebugDescription;
```

returns a normal weight font.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It may help someone.

```
        var style = UIFontTextStyle.Caption2;
        var descriptor = UIFontDescriptor.GetPreferredDescriptorForTextStyle(style);
        var font = UIFont.FromDescriptor(new UIFontDescriptor(new UIFontAttributes
        {
            Family = descriptor.Family,
            Traits = new UIFontTraits
            {
                Weight = (float)GetFontWeight(UIFontWeight.Light)
            }
        }), descriptor.PointSize);
```